# How to add current date and time on this button click on windows form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, button

I am using windows forms application and creating some controls dynamically on form load.

Controls created are Label, UltraDateTimeEditor and Button.

I am using the below code to implement that.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim n = 5
    For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
        'Create label
        Dim label As New Label()
        label.Text = [String].Format("Label {0}", i)
        'Position label on screen
        label.Left = 50
        label.Top = (i + 1) * 30
        label.Width = 70

        'Create UltraDateTimeEditor
        Dim dtpicker = New UltraDateTimeEditor
        dtpicker.Name = "Date" + i.ToString()
        dtpicker.MaskInput = "{date} hh:mm"
        dtpicker.MaskDisplayMode = MaskMode.IncludeBoth
        dtpicker.SpinButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always
        dtpicker.Left = 120
        dtpicker.Top = (i + 1) * 30




        Dim button As New Button()
        'Position textbox on screen
        button.Text = "Now"
        button.Left = 290
        button.Top = (i + 1) * 30
        'Add controls to form
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(label)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(dtpicker)
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(button)
    Next

End Sub
```

The screen looks like this

[image]

Now when the click the Now button beside respective datetimeeditor i need to put the current date and time into respective datetimeeditor.
Please suggest how can i do this.

Comment: If you are creating controls at runtime, you would need to create a method you can use for the button click events (AddHandler)... For example: `AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf UpdateTime`

Comment: Please see [Common Button event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24023022/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix How can i use it for above code. When i click any button it should put current date and time inside respective datetimeditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AddHandler` to your dynamic controls for the `Button` so when they are clicked you can run some code... Please note the: `AddHandler` section...

**Code has been tried and Tested**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim n = 5
        For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
            'Create label
            Dim label As New Label()
            label.Text = [String].Format("Label {0}", i)
            'Position label on screen
            label.Left = 50
            label.Top = (i + 1) * 30
            label.Width = 70

            Dim dtpicker = New UltraDateTimeEditor
            dtpicker.Name = "Date" + i.ToString()
            dtpicker.MaskInput = "{date} hh:mm"
            dtpicker.MaskDisplayMode = MaskMode.IncludeBoth
            dtpicker.SpinButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always
            dtpicker.Left = 120
            dtpicker.Top = (i + 1) * 30
            dtpicker.Tag = i 'Set this as we will use this for comparison



            Dim button As New Button()
            'Position textbox on screen
            button.Text = "Now"
            button.Tag = i 'Set this as we will use this for comparison
            button.Left = 290
            button.Top = (i + 1) * 30
            'Add controls to form
            Me.Controls.Add(label)
            Me.Controls.Add(dtpicker)
            Me.Controls.Add(button)

            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf UpdateTime

        Next

    End Sub
```

This method handles changing the `DateTime` object... We use the `Button.Tag` property and check it against the `DateTime.Tag`. Then we can set the time associated with that `Button`.

```
Private Sub UpdateTime(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim nButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        If nButton IsNot Nothing AndAlso nButton.Tag >= 0 Then
            For Each ctrl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of UltraDateTimeEditor)()
                If ctrl.Tag = nButton.Tag Then
                    ctrl.Value = DateTime.UtcNow
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: For Each ctrl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of UltraDateTimeEditor)()

Comment: I run it just fine... Ctrl is never nothing on my end... If you don't have that type of control on the form it won't jump in the for loop...

Comment: When nButton.Tag is 0 for the first record it never enters into this loop  -->  If nButton IsNot Nothing AndAlso nButton.Tag <> Nothing Then

Comment: @user1030181 `If nButton IsNot Nothing AndAlso nButton.Tag >= 0 Then` use this. For some reason or another `0` gets passed through as Nothing.

Comment: Welcome, this is strange though... The comparison was checking for `Nothing`, but it wasn't it was `0` an Integer... Anyways it works for you!

Comment: @Zaggler...Yes thanks...Another way to try work with this is using

Comment: Private Sub UpdateTime(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button) 'cast the (sender) to a Button to get the instance of the button that was clicked
        DirectCast(btn.Tag, UltraDateTimeEditor).DateTime = Now 'cast the button`s Tag property to a UltraDateTimeEditor and set its DateTime propery to Now
    End Sub

Comment: @user1030181 yes, there are indeed other way's as well :)

Comment: How to loop through all controls in a panel and get datetime value to update in database....Lets say i have SAVE button and when i click save button i want to update my database with latest datetime values that i have entered in the screen

Comment: @user1030181 would you please make this request a new question. The question you asked here was already answered. The reason I ask you to do this is so other users if having the same problem can find it easily. If people start adding more and more information to a question it becomes irrelevant to the first question asked... Thank You!

Comment: @Zaggler...Thank You. Please find my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940569/how-to-loop-through-each-control-inside-the-panel-to-get-value-from-it-and-save

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UserControl with the Label, DatePicker and Button as contained controls, then handle the button event in the UserControl assigning the DateTime.Now value to the DatePicker within the UserControl.

Then replace your original code with the creation of instances of the new UserControl.

You will need properties of the UserControl which are button text and the label within the instance.

Answer (score -1):

To get the current `DateTime` simply use one of two properties (depending on your use case):

```
DateTime.Now
DateTime.UtcNow
```

And then once you have the current `DateTime` you can set the UltraDateTimeEditor's`.Value` property which controls the displayed `DateTime` to one of the *now* properties.

To assign an `EventHandler` for each button you will need to create a Sub that handles the specific button's `.Click` event. However, in order to do this we first must move the button declaration outside of the Form Load events local scope.

```
Dim button(5) As Button
Dim dtpicker(5) As UltraDateTimeEditor

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
    'Create label
    Dim label As New Label()
    label.Text = [String].Format("Label {0}", i)
    'Position label on screen
    label.Left = 50
    label.Top = (i + 1) * 30
    label.Width = 70

    'Create UltraDateTimeEditor
    dtpicker(i) = New UltraDateTimeEditor
    dtpicker(i).Name = "Date" + i.ToString()
    dtpicker(i).MaskInput = "{date} hh:mm"
    dtpicker(i).MaskDisplayMode = MaskMode.IncludeBoth
    dtpicker(i).SpinButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always
    dtpicker(i).Left = 120
    dtpicker(i).Top = (i + 1) * 30

    button(i) = New Button()
    'I assigned the index to the name so we can handle all 5 buttons with one event handler
    button(i).Name = i.ToString()
    'Position textbox on screen
    button(i).Text = "Now"
    button(i).Left = 290
    button(i).Top = (i + 1) * 30
    'Add controls to form
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(label)
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(dtpicker(i))
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(button(i))
Next
End Sub
```

Now the event handler code for the buttons. This will handle all 5 buttons

```
Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttons(0).Click, buttons(1).Click, buttons(2).Click, buttons(3).Click, buttons(4).Click
    Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    dtpicker(CInt(button.Name)).Value = DateTime.Now
End Sub
```

Here we access the index of the related UltraDateTimeEditor array element and set its `.Value` property to the current `DateTime`

Comment: Have you tested this solution by chance? He's not using the standard `DateTimePicker`... Also just showing the code doesn't help either, anyone can google for this. I would assume then this is an incomplete example.

Comment: But my question was something how can we create button click handler for each button and then when they click on any of the now button, it should put the current date and time into respective datetimeeditor

Comment: @user1030181 please see my comment above.

Comment: @zaggler But my question was something how can we create button click handler for each button and then when they click on any of the now button, it should put the current date and time into respective datetimeeditor

Comment: You took his example and it works? I beg to differ as he's creating the controls at runtime, your example (answer) doesnt show any of this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110549/discussion-between-user1030181-and-zaggler).