# How to loop through each control inside the panel to get value from it and save the value from screen to database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, save

How to loop through each control inside the panel to get value from it and save the value from screen to database

Here on this screen i am dynamically creating controls (Label, UltraDateTimeEditor and Button)

I am holding some datetime values in datetimeeditor control. Now in the below screen i have save button.

So when i click save i need to get datetime value from screen and save to database. So i need to loop through each value and save accordingly with its respective row in datatabase.

My code is below.

```
 Private Function LoadFlow()

    Me.Panel1.Controls.Clear()

    If dtDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso dtDataTable IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim n = dtDataTable.Rows.Count

        For i As Integer = 0 To n - 1
            'Create label
            Dim label As New Label()
            label.Text = dtDataTable.Rows(i)("CHECKPOINTNAME").ToString()
            'Position label on screen
            label.Left = 50
            label.Top = (i + 1) * 30
            label.Width = 70

            'Create UltraDateTimeEditor
            Dim dtpicker = New UltraDateTimeEditor
            dtpicker.Name = "Date" + i.ToString()
            dtpicker.MaskInput = "{date} hh:mm"
            dtpicker.MaskDisplayMode = MaskMode.IncludeBoth
            dtpicker.SpinButtonDisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ButtonDisplayStyle.Always
            dtpicker.Left = 120
            dtpicker.Tag = i 'Set this as we will use this for comparison
            dtpicker.Top = (i + 1) * 30


            If Not IsDBNull(dtDataTable.Rows(i)("CheckPointTimeValue")) Then
                dtpicker.Value = dtDataTable.Rows(i)("CheckPointTimeValue")
            Else
                dtpicker.Value = Nothing
            End If

            Dim button As New Button()
            'Position textbox on screen
            button.Tag = i 'Set this as we will use this for comparison
            button.Text = "Now"
            button.Left = 290
            button.Top = (i + 1) * 30
            'Add controls to form
            Me.Panel1.ClientArea.Controls.Add(label)
            Me.Panel1.ClientArea.Controls.Add(dtpicker)
            Me.Panel1.ClientArea.Controls.Add(button)

            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf UpdateTime
        Next
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function


Private Sub UpdateTime(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim nButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        If nButton IsNot Nothing AndAlso nButton.Tag >= 0 Then
            For Each ctrl In Me.Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of UltraDateTimeEditor)()
                If ctrl.Tag = nButton.Tag Then
                    ctrl.Value = DateTime.Now
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
        End If

    End Sub
```

My datatable used for this code looks like this

[image]

My screen looks like this.

[image]

My update SQL Stored Procedure Query

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [TAMS].[pu_InsertCheckPointTimes]
        (
           ,@CheckPointTimeID INT
           ,@CheckPointTimeValue DATETIME = NULL
           ,@LastModifiedUser VARCHAR(128)
        )
    AS
    BEGIN

            IF(@CheckPointTimeID = 0)

    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO [TAMS].[CheckPointTimes]
                   ([CheckPointTimeValue]
                   ,[LastModifiedUser])

             VALUES
                   (@CheckPointTimeValue
                       ,@LastModifiedUser)

    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [TAMS].[CheckPointTimes]
        SET [CheckPointTimeValue] = @CheckPointTimeValue
                  ,[LastModifiedUser] = @LastModifiedUser
        WHERE [CheckPointTimeID] = @CheckPointTimeID
    END

    END
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead assigning an integer to a tag of each control you put inside a panel try to assign it a checkpointid value and then you can do something like this:

```
    For Each o As Object In Panel1.Controls
        If TypeOf (o) Is UltraDateTimeEditor Then
           Dim datePicker as UltraDateTimeEditor = o
           Dim id as Integer = datePicker.Tag
           Dim date as DateTime = datePicker.value
           //save your values

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Cannot use checkpointTimeId value for dtpicker tag. Because sometimes datatable has null value. If you see in above screen shot 2nd record has null value for checkpointtimeid. Because select query is doing left join when no record exist in checkpointtimes table

Comment: Oh, it doesn't really matter if it's null, you just have to care about how to find all values to update. If there's a null value You can just check if it's null before asigning it to a tag and before saving.

Comment: Trying something like this to handle null

Comment: If Not IsDBNull(dtDataTable.Rows(i)("CheckPointTimeID")) Then
                    dtpicker.Tag = dtDataTable.Rows(i)("CheckPointTimeID")
                Else
                    dtpicker.Tag = 0
                End If

Comment: Yep, and in the saving stage, if it is 0 then just insert a null value to a procedure =)

Comment: What if I want to add another id which is (@TerminalCheckPointID) to the same table while saving data. This @TerminalCheckPointID is used as foreign key for the table. If you see my above screen shot of datatable you can understand that.

Comment: If I understood correctly there would be two fields, one with the dateTime and one with CheckPointTimeID right? 

If I'm right it should be better to insert controls in the panel in some different way, for example in the table (where there's a row for each db table row), and then iterate through rows instead of controls.

Comment: Total they are three fields 1) CheckPointTimeId --> Which is primary key of the table 2) TerminalCheckPointID --> Which is forgein key for the table and finally CheckPointTimeValue field

Comment: IMHO the panel is not the best container for what You want to do. It is better to use some control like repeater or a gridview where you can separate each row of the db table. Then You just iterate on each row/item and inside an iteration You can retrieve only controls dedicated to a specific table row. Otherwise you'll need 2 iterations: in the first one you retrieve all new values, separate them on the base of the db field, and store them in a kind of Hashtable, one for each field in the db table. In the latter You simply store new values iterating on 1 of the Hashtables You created before.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by string splitting.

```
 For Each o As Object In Panel1.ClientArea.Controls
        If TypeOf (o) Is UltraDateTimeEditor Then
            Dim datePicker As UltraDateTimeEditor = o
            Dim checkPointTimeID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(0))
            Dim terminalCheckPointID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(datePicker.Tag.Split(","c)(1))
            Dim checkPointTimeValue As System.Nullable(Of DateTime) = datePicker.Value
        End If

    Next
```