# How to get the name of a button that's clicked outside it's individual event procedure

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm pretty new to Visual Basic so sorry if I happen to use the wrong wording.

I have a lot of small buttons on a single form, and was wondering if there was a uniform way to get the name of a button when it's clicked. Since there are so many buttons, I would like to not have to code each individual button to do what I want but instead have 1 method that gets the name of the button when its clicked, and from the name does something. I'm not sure if this is possible at all, but it would make my program much simpler.

Comment: The Title isnt very clear.  When a button is clicked, the click handler is invoked where you can get the name.

Comment: I mean I don't want to have to double click each button and have to code for each individual button if there is a way to do it uni-formally outside of it's individual procedure. Each button will have similar code only altering slightly according to the name of the button.

Comment: Instead of using the generated click handlers, you can create a single handler and in the form load perform an addhandler for every button to your new handler.  Then in the new handler, you'll have a huge select statement (or cascading if-else) on the clicked control name to run the specific code.  But, this is a false benefit, in my opinion - you are creating a single huge routine rather than having smaller specific modules specific to the tasks.  Much harder for future maintenance, generally.

Comment: Please do not add language tags/identifiers to the title - all the cool kids already use tag filters to view the posts which interest them.  No need to click twice - the event args will identify the `sender` which you can pass on to elsewhere.  Please see [Common Button event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24023022/1070452)

Answer (score 1):

Create only one event handler for all buttons

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim name As String = button.Name
    ' use name
End Sub
```

Then you can "attach" this handler to all buttons in the constructor

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponents()

    AddHandler button1.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    AddHandler button2.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    AddHandler button3.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Or use "less readable", in case of big amount of controls, approach - `Handles` keyword

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click,
                                                                   button2.Click,
                                                                   button3.Click,
                                                                   button4.Click
    ' code
End Sub
```

Usually eventhandlers provide instance of the control which raised an event - `sender`
Because type of the parameter is `object` you need cast `parameter` to the type you expected and use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your button naming could be done programmatically then maybe you should be creating the buttons programmatically.  I had a similar problem with text boxes.  here is a part of the code I used to generate them on the fly.  Perhaps you could use it as a model to create buttons on the fly.

```
Private Class cCell
    Private value As Integer
    Private cellTB As TextBox

    Public Sub New(ByVal idx As Integer, ByVal col As Integer, ByVal row As Integer)
        value = 0
        cellTB = mkTB(idx, col, row)
        Form1.Controls.Add(cellTB)
    End Sub

    Private Function mkTB(ByVal idx As Integer, ByVal col As Integer, ByVal row As Integer)
        Dim tb As New TextBox
        tb.Top = Form1.cMargin + row * (Form1.cUnit + Form1.cMargin) + Int(row / 3) * Form1.cMargin * 3
        tb.Left = Form1.cMargin + col * (Form1.cUnit + Form1.cMargin) + Int(col / 3) * Form1.cMargin * 3
        tb.Width = Form1.cUnit
        tb.Height = Form1.cUnit
        tb.Name = "cellTB" & idx.ToString
        tb.Text = ""
        AddHandler tb.TextChanged, AddressOf cCell_TextChanged
        Return tb
    End Function

    Private Sub cCell_TextChanged() ' change text event handler for the cells textbox
        If IsNumeric(cellTB.Text) Then
            If cellTB.Text > 9 Or cellTB.Text < 1 Then
                cellTB.Text = ""
            Else
                cellTB.Font = New Font(cellTB.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
                cellTB.ForeColor = Color.Black
                value = cellTB.Text
                trimPList()
            End If
        Else
            cellTB.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

    Private Sub mkCells()
        Dim idx As Integer
        Dim col As Integer
        Dim row As Integer

        For idx = 0 To 80
            row = Int(idx / 9)
            col = idx Mod 9
            aCells(idx) = New cCell(idx, col, row)
        Next
    End Sub
```